# Laravel: how to cache config files properly

Tags: php, laravel, caching, backend

I'm using Laravel 8.0 in my application and I added a new **.env** variable:

```
APP_URL_FRONT=https://tmsv00008:6204
```

And how I use it:

```
To access the project use the following link: <a href="{{ env('APP_URL_FRONT') }}/projects/{{ $project->id }}">LINK</a>
```

When I deploy the application I cache the config files:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

But the env files is not visible and the strange thing is that if I execute:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

The variable is visible.
What I'm doing wrong? Because it doesn't make sense to me.

Also, in [this article](https://linuxhint.com/laravel-is-not-reading-env-file-after-change/) they suggest to execute the commands in this order:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

But this doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't be the other way around? And I think the cache commands also clears the cache first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `env()` function is strongly recommended to be used only in configuration file, since caching the configurations, will make the `env` function to return `null`

In other words, crate a configuration file, with that environment variable, or add it to an existing one

It's hidden in an old [update guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) this "note"

Comment: Or can I use other function?

Comment: @NicuVlad mmm no... my suggestion is to add to an existing file (like the `app` one)and then use `config('app.url_front)`

Comment: Got it. Let me try

Comment: It worked! Tx!!